# Need help Linq query join + count + group by

Tags: linq

I have two table

First table

```
BID Town
1   ABC
2   ABC2
3   ABC
```

Second Table

```
PID BID AmountFirst AmountSecond AmountThird Minority
1   1   1000       1000          1000        SC
2   2   2000       1000          2000        ST
3   3   1000       1000          1000        SC
```

BID is foreign key in Second table.
I want sum AmountFirst + AmountSecond + AmountThird  for individualTown 
e.g for ABC town answer should be : 6000 (summation of PID 1 and PID 2)
I want Linq query for this..Please help

Comment: Check the manual for the wiki markup. You really don't need to write manual breaks and all that (see my edit of your question)

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but something like this should work. See [hooked on linq - GroupBy operator](http://www.hookedonlinq.com/GroupByOperator.ashx) for groupby syntax.

```
from bid in db.Bids
group by bid.Town into g
select new
{
  Town = g.Key,
  Total = g.Sum(x => x.AmountFirst + x.AmountSecond + x.AmountThird)
}
```

`Town` is now a number, you can also do:

```
Town = g.Key.Town
```